# Using an NPM package with dependencies in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, npm

I'm trying to use an NPM package in my meteor project but I have some problems getting it to work.

The module I’m trying to use is this **[steam](https://www.npmjs.com/package/steam)** package. 
I’ve added the **[meteorhacks:npm](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/npm)** package for meteor and changed the **packages.json** file to:

```
{
  "steam": "0.6.8",
    "adm-zip": "0.4.7",
    "buffer-crc32": "0.2.5",
    "bytebuffer": "3.5.4",
      "bufferview": "1.0.1",
      "long": "2.2.3",
    "protobufjs": "4.0.0-b2",
      "ascli": "1.0.0",
        "optjs": "3.2.1-boom",
      "colour": "0.7.1"
}
```

*(to clarify the above, it’s the steam package with all its dependencies and the dependencies of the dependencies)*

Now I’ve tried to use the package in my meteor app with this code located in -/server/steambot/steambot.js

```
var Steam = Meteor.npmRequire('steam');
var bot = new Steam.SteamClient();
bot.logOn({  // (fake credentials)
    accountName: 'a', 
    password: '123456789',
    authCode: 'aaa55',
    shaSentryfile: 'aaa'
});
```

I hoped it would be as easy as that but then the errors started.

> var cryptedSessKey =
>   require('crypto').publicEncrypt(fs.readFileSync(__dirna TypeError:
>   Object # has no method 'publicEncrypt'

I figured out it’s the `require()` function of the steam and dependencie packages that’s giving me these errors. If I replace the `require()` with `Meteor.npmRequire()` I just go the the `next require()` function in one of the NPM packages.

Is there a way to fix this issue without changing *every require()* function to `Meteor.npmRequire()`?

And even if I should what is the best approach?

I'm also quite new to the NPM and Meteor world, is this kind of workflow the way I should be doing it and/or are there any improvements I could make or keep in mind?

Comment: Have you tried adding *only* `steam` to the `packages.json`? - NPM should resolve dependencies by itself.

Comment: Yes I have. The error stays the same.

Comment: Im running  an example with the same `package.json` and the 2 lines code snippet you put on the question and im not getting any errors, wich meteor version are you using? `meteor --version`, or did you have more code apart this 2 lines? put that conde inside a `Meteor.startup(function(){})` to check if that still happened  the requires

Comment: @Ethaan I forgot to mention that I also used the login command afterwards. I edited the post for the command. Fake or legit credentials both give the same error.

Comment: @Ethaan wrapping the code in `Meteor.startup(function(){})` does not fix it either. (running Meteor 1.1)

Comment: im looking into this, its weird seems if you `console.log(bot)` you get something like this. `{ domain: null, _events: {}, _maxListeners: 10 }` so im looking if there is something missing to use the `logOn method` i see this note too **Note: only Node.js v0.12 and io.js v1.4 are supported.**

Comment: Seems like this is a node version problem, steam only supports `nodev 0.12` and meteor `v1.1 use node: 0.10.36 (from 0.10.33)` check the [history.md](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md)

Answer (score 1):

**Update: As of July 2016 Meteor 1.4 uses Node 4.4.7, which does support the stream npm package (requires 4.1.1+)**

The Steam NPM plugin will not work with Meteor.

The NPM package page (https://www.npmjs.com/package/steam) states:

> Note: only Node.js **v0.12** and io.js v1.4 are supported.

Meteor is using an older version of NodeJS. E.g. Meteor v1.0.4 (March 17, 2015) uses **v0.10.36**

Meteor has very short release cycles, but I doubt that Node v0.12 will be supported anytime soon considering that Meteor v0.8.1.1 (May 1, 2014) was using Node v0.10.26.